# Is there a way in ClosedXml to shift the range of a conditional format?

Tags: .net, closedxml

I'm using a template file to generate Excel reports.  After the report has been generated the first column is deleted as that column contains metadata to control the report generation. All other formatting is coming over correctly the data is correct, but when the first column is deleted, the Conditional formats are not updated.  Is there a way to update this?

```
List<IXLRow> templateHeaderRows, templateDetailRows, templateFooterRows;
GetRowLists(templateWorksheet, out templateHeaderRows, out templateDetailRows, out templateFooterRows);
ProcessRows(newWorksheet, templateHeaderRows, templateDetailRows, templateFooterRows);

newWorksheet.Column(1).Delete();
templateWorksheet.Delete();
```

Comment: Do you have event tracking enabled or disabled? `var wb = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled);`

Comment: @Raidri I didn't know about that.  I'm very new to ClosedXml.  I will check as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @Raidri Unfortunately that did not work.  In fact disabling caused another issue.  I'm starting to think that this is a bug in the library.